# Finding href from 'a' tag is not finding the first 'a' tag, how do i fix it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I am new to python and I am trying to scrape indeed. for some reason, each job post is saved under 'a' tag instead of a div, which also contains the href.
This is the item output: print(item)

```
<a class="tapItem fs-unmask result job_e0fb3e5f520856c0 resultWithShelf sponTapItem tapItem-noPadding desktop" data-hide-spinner="true" data-jk="e0fb3e5f520856c0" data-mobtk="1favs1gn0t5v1800" href="/company/Acentury/jobs/New-Graduate-Software-Developer-e0fb3e5f520856c0?fccid=5c6453896b020232&amp;vjs=3" id="job_e0fb3e5f520856c0" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><div class="slider_container"><div class="slider_list"><div class="slider_item"><div class="job_seen_beacon"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="jobCard_mainContent" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="resultContent"><div class="heading4 color-text-primary singleLineTitle tapItem-gutter"><h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob"><div class="new topLeft holisticNewBlue desktop"><span class="label">new</span></div><span title="New Graduate Software Developer">New Graduate Software Developer</span></h2></div><div class="heading6 company_location tapItem-gutter"><pre><span class="companyName">Acentury</span><div class="companyLocation">Richmond Hill, ON<span class="remote-bullet">•</span><span>Temporarily Remote</span></div></pre></div><div class="heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer"><div class="metadata salary-snippet-container"><span class="salary-snippet">$44,182 - $126,699 a year</span></div></div><div class="heading6 error-text tapItem-gutter"></div></td></tr></tbody></table><table class="jobCardShelfContainer" role="presentation"><tbody><tr class="jobCardShelf"><td class="shelfItem indeedApply"><span class="iaIcon"></span><span class="ialbl iaTextBlack">Easily apply</span></td></tr><tr class="underShelfFooter"><td><div class="heading6 tapItem-gutter result-footer"><div class="job-snippet"><ul style="list-style-type:circle;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;padding-left:20px;">
<li>Work with senior <b>developers</b> to develop front-end features on our current platform through entire R&amp;D cycle from design to implementation and official release.</li>
</ul></div><span class="date">Today</span><span class="result-link-bar-separator">·</span><button aria-expanded="false" class="sl resultLink more_links_button" type="button">More...</button></div><div class="tab-container"><div class="more-links-container result-tab" role="presentation"><div class="more_links"><button class="close-button" title="Close" type="button"></button><ul><li><span class="mat">View all <a href="/Acentury-jobs">Acentury jobs</a> - <a href="/jobs-in-Richmond-Hill,-ON">Richmond Hill jobs</a></span></li><li><span class="mat">Salary Search: <a href="/career/software-engineer/salaries/Richmond-Hill--ON?campaignid=serp-more&amp;fromjk=e0fb3e5f520856c0&amp;from=serp-more">New Graduate Software Developer salaries in Richmond Hill, ON</a></span></li></ul></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table><div aria-live="polite"></div></div></div><div class="slider_sub_item"></div></div></div><div class="kebabMenu"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Job actions" class="kebabMenu-button"><svg fill="none" height="24" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M12 7C13.1 7 14 6.1 14 5C14 3.9 13.1 3 12 3C10.9 3 10 3.9 10 5C10 6.1 10.9 7 12 7ZM12 10C10.9 10 10 10.9 10 12C10 13.1 10.9 14 12 14C13.1 14 14 13.1 14 12C14 10.9 13.1 10 12 10ZM12 17C10.9 17 10 17.9 10 19C10 20.1 10.9 21 12 21C13.1 21 14 20.1 14 19C14 17.9 13.1 17 12 17Z" fill="#2d2d2d"></path></svg></button></div></a>
```

and my code is

```
divs = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tapItem')
for item in divs:
   for people in item.find_all('a'):
       print(people)   
       for ok in people.find_all('a', class_ = 'tapItem'):
           linkJob1 = ok.get('href')
   print(linkJob1)
```

The people does not contain the first 'a' tag but the other ones, How do I fix this? Thank you

url: https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Toronto%2C+ON&start=0

the expected result is the href of each job post/card

Comment: what's the url and an example expected result?

Comment: https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Toronto%2C+ON&start=0

the expected result is the href of each job post/card

Answer (score 2):

You just need one of the ids (the job id), which you can extract from the `data-jk` attribute, if you loop at the level of elements with class `result`. You can then, as the website does, construct the url dynamically:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Toronto,+ON&start=0')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for job in soup.select('.result'):
    print(job.select_one('.jobTitle').get_text(' '))
    print(f'https://ca.indeed.com/viewjob?jk={job["data-jk"]}')
```

Comment: how do i get the full job description of job post/card? When you click on the job card preview thing, in 'no scraping' mode, it just opens the full job description on the right. I would very much like to get that full description when scraping